# Guru of Sita, Guru of Draupadi

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, guru, sita, draupadi

Sita and Draupadi are Special characters in Ramayan and Mahabharat.
Both showed strong mind and devotion!
Both have no biological birth! What does it represent? That high Level is not possible for earthly bring's?
Especially Sita , morning remembering character, Symbol of dedication to husband. Who was Guru of Sita?
Did draupadi had any Guru, need to go to any school as she was not born as child?

Comment: Yeah, I think there is figurative meaning behind the situation of both women having no biological birth, for sure. Are they both in the list of PanchKanya too also ? I know list includes Tara & Mandodari from Ramayan, then google says Ahalya too. Interesting. There also men in Hindu-mytho who didn’t have biological birth ? Some meaning is there, with these figures 